# Git Diff Between Commits and Pull

Tags: git, diff

I have git commit history:

```
commit: abasued1.. <-- commit for changes in file A.java
commit: jsdiq7di.. <-- commit for changes in file A.java
commit: 2348fbvb.. <-- result from git pull origin master
commit: 0123ruhw.. <-- commit for changes in file A.java
```

Is there any way to see `git diff 0123ruhw jsdiq7di abasued1` the same way without `2348fbvb` is committed?

If let's say I never `git pull origin master`, I would be able to run `git diff 0123ruhw jsdiq7di abasued1` nicely with a combined diff changes of file A.java.

However, since I did `git pull origin master` in between, I am not able to use `git diff 0123ruhw jsdiq7di abasued1` to see combined changes against file A.java.

Is there any way to get the combined diff changes against file A.java and exclude the `git pull` commit changes?

Please advise

Thanks!

Comment: Please give a graph of your revisions (including the common ancestor of your commits and any merges), and what you want to see.

Comment: Thanks @Rudi for your interest.

What I want to see is git diff 0123ruhw jsdiq7di abasued1 as if the commit: 2348fbvb is never existed.